# Is it correct to say something like "An issue is being had by them"

Tags: meaning, phrases, idioms, ambiguity

One can say "We're having this issue". But is it too awkward to, instead, say "This issue is being had by us", or would the meaning change completely?

Comment: Outside of a very few fixed idioms (*a good time was had by all* etc), we do not use the verb *have* in passive constructions. So one might view your sentence as either awkward of ungrammatical.

Comment: One purpose of using a passive form is to mask the agent. But do you want to sound like the issue is so mysterious or the agent is an unknown secret? I'd compromise on "An issue we're facing is ..."

Comment: Yes, that's why the _by_-phrase is less common than its absence with passives. If you want to de-emphasize it, why keep it around?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. This is especially true if a learner tries to transform "It was nice having you" into a passive response "Thank you. It was nice being had" which, of course, happens to be its own idiom *to be had,* meaning to be tricked or fooled by someone.

Comment: In a humorous context only.

Comment: You can say it but one generally would not. You'd say: We are the ones having the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, "to have" cannot occur in the passive voice when used in this sense. Instead, "to be had" is an idiom [defined by Collins as:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/to-be-had)

> If you have been had, someone has tricked you, for example by selling you something at too high a price.
> [Example:] *If your customer thinks he's been had, you have to make
> him happy.*

Since an issue cannot be tricked, "This issue is being had by us" makes no semantic sense, though it is not (strictly speaking) ungrammatical.